# GEE collection bands from formulas

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How could I create a function calculating NDVI difference from actual NDVI and mean NDVI values to add as a new band to the collection?

Something like this:

```
var ndvi_diff = ndvi.map(function (image) {
  return image.subtract(ndvi_mean).addBands('ndvi_diff');
});
```

Can I do calculations with different image collections?

Note that I don’t want to reduce the collection into a single image but I would like  to have the mean and then the calculated formula for all images in the same collection as new bands.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this question: [Calculating the vegetation condition indices over a stacked vegetation indices in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411196/calculating-the-vegetation-condition-indices-over-a-stacked-vegetation-indices-i/411198?noredirect=1#comment667788_411198)

You could try something like this:

```
var getdiff = function(image){
  var diff = image.subtract(meanImage).rename('ndvi_diff')
  
  return diff // only the vci
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9a0d7ac049865ef12eea34e13871cb12